# AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh resolution for iPhone 4S and 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avcapturesession

I am developing camera application using AVCaptureSession. I set AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh for sessionPreset.Now I want to know the resolution for all devices with this configuration.I search with Apple document.I got  [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html)

But in this document i cant find iPhone4S and 5 resolution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why in god's name does Apple not give us an API for this :(

Comment: Check here for device resolutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422322/method-to-find-devices-camera-resolution-ios

Answer (score -3):

iPhone 4S and 5 have the same capture resolutions : Full HD from back camera and HD from front camera.